# Setting authorisation in a database using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm working on a uni homework project of a shopping web page for which I'm trying to set up a database. My problem is in how to set roles to my database. I want to have two roles: Costumer and Administrator. I want my Costumer to be able to register, log in, validate e-mail, add a product to the cart and complete the purchase. Administrator role should be able to add, edit and remove articles, add, edit and remove costumers, and publish sales. My question is: what would be the simplest working solution to set the roles and restrictions for this situation?

I just started this project so don't have much to show but I searched the web for this topic and found several solutions which weren't well explained or contained technologies unsuitable for my project. I am working with C# and ASP.net, using standard MVC and Entity framework provided by Visual Studio 2017 IDE. 
Here are two models I created and intend to use. I used MVC5 to generate views and controllers for those models, adding them to the context and the database.

```
  public class Administrator
{
    [Key]
    public int AId { get; set; }
    public string AName { get; set; }
    public string ALastName { get; set; }
    public string AEmail { get; set; }
    public string APassword { get; set; }
}

 public class Costumer
{
    [Key]
    public int CId { get; set; }
    public string CName { get; set; }
    public string CLastName { get; set; }
    public string CEmail { get; set; }
    public string CPassword { get; set; }
    public string CAdress { get; set; }
    public string CGender { get; set; }
    public DateTime CBirthDate { get; set; }
}
```

I was suggested to set up separate Role table to store roleId and roleName and attempt setting roles by connecting and matching roleId with AId and CId. So far, not succesfull

Comment: You should use Role based authentication using Asp.NET Identity framework.. It has all the features that you need and tables will be automatically created.

Comment: Here is the simple example for you https://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet-mvc/1102/aspnet-mvc-role-based-security

Answer (score 0):

You could use Role based Authentication of Identity Framework, or you could do it your way.
You should change your database models a little bit.
Here what you can do,

```
public class Actions{
   [Key]
   public int ActionId {get; set;}
   public string Action {get; set;}    
}

public class Users{
   [Key]
   public int UserId { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string LastName { get; set; }
   public string Email { get; set; }
   public string Password { get; set; }
   public string Adress { get; set; }
   public string Gender { get; set; }
   public Nullable<DateTime > BirthDate { get; set; }
}

public class Roles{
   [Key]
   public int RoleId {get; set;}
   public string RoleName {get; set;}
   public string RolePermissions {get; set;} // You will store action IDs in "1,2,4,5"  this format
}

public class UserRole{
   [Key]
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public int UserId {get; set;}
   public int RoleId {get; set;}
}
```

You should store roles inside `Role` table because you may need to add more roles in future, and manage users in one table. `UserRole` table will contain all of your roles assigned to specific user. Each role will have a set of Action permission. Those actions will be stored in `Actions` table and saved as comma oriented string into `RolePermissions` column.

You need to setup a simple check function before each operation whether this user has right permission to do this operation? It will be a simple injection check before each database operation.

You could store current user permission in `Session` at the time of login and use it afterwards.

I think this will help when your application grows and solve your problem.